# Where is Winnt.h file in VS2005

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-c++-6

I am reading Charles Petzold's Programming windows. 5th Edition.  And there is a statement to `Windows.h` file.

It said.

> There is a `WINNT.H` file included in `Windows.h` file.
>
> And the `WINNT.H` file used to define Unicode support.

But I can't find it in Visual Studio 8.0 `Windows.h` file.

And the file (`WINNT.H`) is not existing in `Windows.h` in VS 8.0, How can the Unicode support function be realized?

Comment: As paulsm4 mentioned, you should already have winnt.h.  However, in any case, you should probably get the latest Windows SDK from the Microsoft Download Center and use these header files instead of the older ones included in VS2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Visual C++ component of Visual Studio installed (i.e. if you can compile .cpp files), then you have WINNT.H.  As well as Windows.h (which implicitly #include's WINNT.H for all Win32 targets).

It should be under "\includes" in your MSVS install directory.

In earlier versions of MSVS, 8-bit ASCII was the default, and you had to explictly "#define _UNICODE" (e.g. as a compile option).  Newer versions (I believe starting in MSVS2005, but certainly now in MSVS2008 and MSVS2010), 16-bit Unicode is the default.

Comment: Hi, I do find my winnt.h in my include folder. But I still confused that how the windows.h include the winnt.h. Since I don't find't the line of `#include <winnt.h>` in my windows.h. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies - my bad.  I've got a million different compilers, from DOS/Win3.0 Watcom and Borland up to MSVS2010.  Winnt.h USED to be shipped with OLD Win 3.0 and Win98 compilers; it USED to be called from windows.h via windef.h.  It's only needed in platform SDK's nowdays - you DON'T have it/don't need it in MSVS 2005 or higher.  Just use windows.h (which uses winbase.h), and you'll be fine.  The  Petzold examples should work unchanged - just with windows.h, instead of winnt.h.  Sorry about the confusion...